# Laravel 4 [API] how do i check if i already logged in from the consumer?

Tags: api, session, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I've been creating API and consumer by following Simple API Development with Laravel from Aaron Kuzemchak. I got the problem after I success to auth via API from my consumer; I do not know how to check it, if the consummer already success logged in or not at the other pages...

For example, at the first; I show the login page, click the submit button to check the credentials via API. The login attempt is working, success to logged in and redirect to dashboard. But, if I haven't logged in and accessed the dashboard from URL, i got the dashboard :O

The API server and the consumer have separated machine and the database only exists at the API server.

- Am I doing this right (with the flow for the API and Consumer) ?
- At the consumer, how can I get to know if the user already logged in or not (after success attempt the credential)? (somehow? someidea?)

Thank you before... :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very confusing, probably because I haven't watched that screencast yet, but shouldn't `Auth::check()` be what you are looking for?  It will return true or false depending on if the user is logged in.

Comment: It looks like the poster wants to authenticate against a back end API of some variety

Comment: auth::check() only can be made at the API server and can not be done since: the API use session as array, so when the next request from the client, the sessions already gone and the auth::check() will always return false...

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure:

- You have a back end API built from the tutorial posted here: http://kuzemchak.net/blog/entry/laracon-slides-and-video
- You're using HTTP Basic authentication as described in the above tutorial
- You're building a (consumer) front end web interface for users on a separate server
- Your consumer interface uses forms based authentication (a login form)

The backend API uses HTTP basic authentication (and the consumer sends an API key for the user with each request). As such, the backend won't keep track of a user being logged in. That means your consumer interface will need to do this.

You could use the Laravel Auth class for this normally, but your front end would normally have access to the database and the bundled authentication drivers could just check a username/password.

I'd say your options are:

- Store details of the user in a session using the Session class (feels a bit nasty but simple)
- Write an authentication driver and then use the Auth class (advanced but cleaner: http://www.karlvalentin.de/1903/write-your-own-auth-driver-for-laravel-4.html)
- Just talk straight to the database using the existing Auth class and Eloquent

Comment: so, the API send the users detail (after success logged in) and the front end store them in local sessions and at every request from the front end to the API, it brings some of the sessions to process?